# inconsistency while creating new array with existing array in javascript/ typescript in angular 6

Tags: javascript

Please see below code

```
var data = [
    {id: 1, name: 'aa'},
    {id: 2, name: 'ab'},
    {id: 3, name: 'ac'},
    {id: 4, name: 'ad'},
    {id: 5, name: 'ae'},
];
console.log(data);
var obj = Array.from(data);
obj.forEach((val) => delete val.name);
console.log(obj);
console.log(data);
```

while printing the obj, data arrays, name property in  data array is also removing.
**how to create new array with existing array??** . if we add/delete any properties in new array that changes should not reflect on the source array..

Comment: what error do you have ? it has to work with `Array.from` method

Comment: Not an error, but while doing modifications changes are reflecting to the source array, but i don't want to disturb the source array: please provide any solution

Comment: you map(), instead of foreach,

Comment: weird, it should not reference to the source

Comment: @Vinod, not resolved? with map()